# Questions asking for links

Tags: discussion

Questions asking for links to third party resources or examples aren't allowed on SO. It seems they are allowed here or are they said to be banned somewhere?

[Example question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/129777/any-good-examples-of-timeline-components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, they're not suitable for here. Far too many possible answers, and a link isn't an answer to anything, it's just a link to somewhere.

If you see such questions (or link-only answers) then vote to close or flag for moderator attention.